# go: stub method that outputs result in its input parameter

Tags: unit-testing, reflection, go

In the past few days I have been trying to solve a problem, and I understand that I don't have enough insight to do so.

**Intro**

I have wrapped a `json.NewDecoder(r).Decode(v)` in a struct that looks like this

```
t := new(validTransport)
v := make([]foo, 0)
t.Decode(r, &v)
```

and now `v` holds all the foos that are read from `r`.

**Problem**

My problem is how do I stub the values that will be set to `v` when I try to unit test something that has a dependency to `validTransport`.

In my attempt to fix this I have defined a interface `Transport` on which my functionallity will depend.

```
type Transport interface{
  Decode(r io.Reader, v interface{})
}
```

In the unit test I define a `fakeTransport` and pass it instead of the real implementation. **The problem is how do I stub what values will be set to `v`** when `Decode` gets called.

**My not working solution**

I have been using [testify](https://github.com/stretchr/testify) in order to mock my dependencies that provides a quite nice api to do so.

Code sample:

```
type fakeTransport struct{
   mock.Mock
   stubValue interface{}
}

func (f *fakeTransport) Decode(r io.Reader, v interface{}){
   f.Called(r,v)  // assert that this function has been called
   want := reflect.ValueOf(f.stubValue)
   reflect.ValueOf(v).Set(want) //stub my value here
}
```

**Question**

So my question is how exactly should I deal with methods with such signature that they have their return value actually be one of the input parameters.

If the signature was something like:

```
type Transport interface{
   Decode(r io.Reader) interface{}
}
```

then i will just have my stubbed value returned (but that would also enforce the need to do a type assertion which I don't want).

**Edit**

Here is a pseudo [gist](https://gist.github.com/NewestUser/631b7f52ef1b812f1d2f) illustrating how currently I am accomplishing this.

Comment: Why are you decoding transport from JSON?

Comment: I assume you are asking why am I wrapping the JSON api. It is because I am using a set of validation rules that will be applied to the decoded struct from the json object. That way I can guarantee that non valid structs will enter my api further down the chain.

Comment: You need to provide more details about structure of your program, it is quite difficult to give any advice based on the information you provided.

Comment: I have added a gist that shows what I am currently doing in order to stub the value.

Comment: I think your reflect part is wrong.
Is that what you want? http://play.golang.org/p/khUJv2t6W6

Comment: I'm not sure what is the difference between reflect.Indirect and reflect.ValueOf().Elem() it seems to work both ways as long as I pass a pointer.